# align environment with multicols not starting on top of the column

Tags: multicol

I want to make tree columns wit an simple equation. Problem is that the first equation in the environment align is not aligned on top of the column. With text I don't have that problem:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,addpoints,twoside]{exam} 
\usepackage{geometry} 
\geometry{a4paper} 
\geometry{margin=1in} 

\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{marvosym} 
\usepackage{multicol} 
\setlength{\columnsep}{20pt}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.3pt} 



\begin{document}

\section{Oplossen van vergelijkinegn}
Voorbeeldopgaven:
\begin{multicols}{2}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec dapibus lectus sed sollicitudin venenatis. Ut ut convallis elit. Morbi non tortor faucibus, facilisis nisl et, faucibus nunc. Nunc faucibus et massa non venenatis. Phasellus sed lorem id ex fermentum auctor. Aenean blandit velit vel augue ultrices dictum. Praesent nec tortor pharetra, facilisis tellus sed, ullamcorper ipsum. Sed in odio pellentesque, interdum ex vitae, laoreet ante. Vestibulum dui erat, cursus sit amet pulvinar vel, convallis ut risus. Sed fringilla, lacus sit amet tempor finibus, felis purus elementum nulla, nec condimentum nisl erat vitae ante. Proin iaculis odio eget aliquam aliquam. In ac leo ex. Phasellus ut risus ut libero lobortis pretium vitae sit amet arcu. Aliquam ipsum ex, vulputate quis arcu et, porta sodales mauris. Phasellus pellentesque tellus vel venenatis dignissim. Phasellus id ullamcorper velit, vel hendrerit sapien.
\end{multicols}

\begin{multicols}{3}
\begin{align*}
    x+3&=7 \\
    x&=7-3\\
    x&=4
\end{align*}
\columnbreak
\begin{align*}
    x-5&=7 \\
    x&=7+5\\
    x&=12
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
    -x+2&=6 \\
    -x&=6-2\\
    -x&=4\\
    x&=-4
\end{align*}
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

[image]

So how can I make the first equation to be aligned at the top of the column?

Comment: Using `\noindent` in the first column seems to be the solution (or workaround). See [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/332060/94691).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you missed `\noindent` in the first column.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,addpoints,twoside]{exam} 
\usepackage{geometry} 
\geometry{a4paper} 
\geometry{margin=1in} 

\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{marvosym} 
\usepackage{multicol} 
\setlength{\columnsep}{20pt}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.3pt} 



\begin{document}

\section{Oplossen van vergelijkinegn}
Voorbeeldopgaven:
\begin{multicols}{2}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec dapibus lectus sed sollicitudin venenatis. Ut ut convallis elit. Morbi non tortor faucibus, facilisis nisl et, faucibus nunc. Nunc faucibus et massa non venenatis. Phasellus sed lorem id ex fermentum auctor. Aenean blandit velit vel augue ultrices dictum. Praesent nec tortor pharetra, facilisis tellus sed, ullamcorper ipsum. Sed in odio pellentesque, interdum ex vitae, laoreet ante. Vestibulum dui erat, cursus sit amet pulvinar vel, convallis ut risus. Sed fringilla, lacus sit amet tempor finibus, felis purus elementum nulla, nec condimentum nisl erat vitae ante. Proin iaculis odio eget aliquam aliquam. In ac leo ex. Phasellus ut risus ut libero lobortis pretium vitae sit amet arcu. Aliquam ipsum ex, vulputate quis arcu et, porta sodales mauris. Phasellus pellentesque tellus vel venenatis dignissim. Phasellus id ullamcorper velit, vel hendrerit sapien.
\end{multicols}

\begin{multicols}{3}
\noindent\begin{align*}
    x+3&=7 \\
    x&=7-3\\
    x&=4
\end{align*}
\columnbreak
\begin{align*}
    x-5&=7 \\
    x&=7+5\\
    x&=12
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
    -x+2&=6 \\
    -x&=6-2\\
    -x&=4\\
    x&=-4
\end{align*}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image]